# Probability distribution (pdf)

Tags: probability

I have this problem:

20% of items produced on a machine are outside tolerance. Determine the probability distribution of the number of defectives in a pack of five items.

I have came to the conclusion that sample size = 5 but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level.

Answer (score 2):

It is a probability distribution supported on $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. You just have to give the 6 values of the probability mass function; assuming the fact that a given item is faulty is independent of the others, let $X$ be the number of defectives in the set. You get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\{X=0\} &= \left(1-\frac{20}{100}\right)^5 \tag{All are good} \\
\mathbb{P}\{X=1\} &= \binom{5}{1}\left(1-\frac{20}{100}\right)^4\left(\frac{20}{100}\right)^1 \tag{One is bad out of 5} \\
\vdots
\end{align*}

You can explicitly compute them. Note that this is actually a binomial distribution $\operatorname{Binom}(0.2, 5)$ — can you see intuitively why?

Answer (score 1):

The question wether one of the items is okay (or not okay) does not depend on the condition of the others. Secondly the items have all the same probability of being okay (or not okay). This tells you that you deal here with a **binomial distribution**. You only must find the correct parameters. Can you take it from here?

The pdf of a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ is:$$P_{X}\left(k\right)=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}$$